# SQL query to find if values in a column contain specific substring in specific position in a string

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a Query to select all values from a column that contain specific substring in specific position in a string

EXAMPLE: let's say I have a column with phone numbers (all contain 10 characters).

I need to select all phone numbers from a column where in positions 6,7,8 there is a string '433'. Datatype of the column is `CLOB`.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely. Datatype `CLOB` isn't a "regular" SQL datatype that any RDBMS will support ....

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can do this with using substring. Note, this is for SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    PhoneNumber NVARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (PhoneNumber) VALUES
('8004331234'),
('8001313143'),
('8004334321'),
('8004343334')

SELECT * FROM @temp
WHERE SUBSTRING(PhoneNumber,4,3) = '433'
```

This checks position 4, 5, and 6 for the string "433".